# How to do a search for the selected text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I search for the selected text in the current file without having to **copy / ctrl-f / paste**?

**For clarification:** Ultraedit has this behaviour. When pressed `F3` and there's no selected text it performs the last search, if there is a selected text then it searches for the selected text in the current file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultraedit-way search is my favorite and it's really convenient: single 'F3' key can handle all.

The drawback of `Ctrl+D` is: it **cannot** wrap around the search.

To be clear, the definition of Ultraedit-way search is:
When pressed F3 and there's no selected text it performs the last search, if there is a selected text then it searches for the selected text in the current file.

Here is the absolutely 100%-compatible solution to Ultraedit-way search:

- When text is selected, do nextSelectionMatchFindAction
- When no text is selected, do nextMatchFindAction
- Single `F3` does both above.
- `Shift+F3` keeps its original: Find Previous

Therefore `keybindings.json` can add the following lines to disable original `F3` and `Ctrl+F3` functions, and add two new `F3` functions when text is selected and not selected.

```
{
    "key": "f3",
    "command": "editor.action.nextSelectionMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorFocus && editorHasSelection"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+f3",
    "command": "-editor.action.nextSelectionMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorFocus"
},
{
    "key": "f3",
    "command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorFocus && !editorHasSelection"
},
{
    "key": "f3",
    "command": "-editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

And one more thing to be addressed:
When `F3` is pressed, the search dialog is appeared and every matched text is highlighted, you can press `ESC` to dismiss search dialog when search is done.

Update @2021/1/25
If anyone wants `Shift+F3` to works as smart as `F3`, add the following line into  `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "shift+f3",
    "command": "editor.action.previousSelectionMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorFocus && editorHasSelection"
},
{
    "key": "shift+f3",
    "command": "editor.action.previousMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorFocus && !editorHasSelection"
},
{
    "key": "shift+f3",
    "command": "-editor.action.previousMatchFindAction",
    "when": "editorFocus"
},
```

Answer (score 7):

Enable the `editor.find.seedSearchStringFromSelection` setting as seen below. This will cause highlighted texted to automatically be searched when you press ctrl+f.

[image]

Comment: In order to enable this setting, you should open your user settings with `Crtl+,` or `Command+,`

Comment: how about ctrl+shift+f?

Answer (score 1):

I have found what I was looking for.

`Ctrl+D` triggers the action **Add Selection To Next Find Match** which does exactly what I wanted: perform an immediate search for the selected text, just like `F3` in Ultraedit.

Comment: The answer from @jackie-yeh is better than mine.